# python pandas groupby unexpected empty column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to aggregate some data to append to a dataframe. The following gives me the number of wins per name
    import pandas as pd

```
data = [[1,'tom', 10], [1,'nick', 15], [2,'juli', 14], [2,'peter', 20], [3,'juli', 3], [3,'peter', 13]] 

have = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Round', 'Winner', 'Score']) 

WinCount= have.groupby(['Winner']).size().to_frame('WinCount')
WinCount
```

, but the output does not give me two columns, named Winner and WinCount. In stead, the first column has no name, and the column name then appears on the second line:

[image: output:]

How can I get a dataframe without these two "blank" fields

Comment: Use `WinCount=have.groupby(['Winner']).size().reset_index(name='WinCount')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
WinCount=have.groupby(['Winner']).size().to_frame('WinCount').reset_index()
```

**Output**

```
    Winner  WinCount
0   juli    2
1   nick    1
2   peter   2
3   tom     1
```

Comment: I only want one row per name\winner, not to append to the original dataframe

Comment: code updated, please check. Initially i thought you wanted the row appended to the original dataframe.

Comment: excellent, reset_index seems to be my new best friend!